# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am getting this error. mostly error i checked getting a erro about null object  refernce

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     //SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper;
    //SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
      String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,mobileArray);
        ListView mylistView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

here is the main.xml file

```
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

          android:layout_width="match_parent"

          android:layout_height="match_parent"

          tools:context="com.example.myapplication5.app.MainActivity"

          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="attr/actionBarSize"

        android:background="attr/colorPrimary"/> 
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:id="@+id/listView1" />



</LinearLayout>
```

this is the listview through which the adapter is connected

Comment: How do you want people to help if you don't specify the error log. Guys, before posting any stuff on stackverflow please look a bit at the structure of a correct post. In short, what you did, what is the error and some codes/data where the error happens. Everything should be as relevant as possible.

Comment: used by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.myapplication5.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)

Comment: please add the logcat report to question...neyways your myListView is null make sure you have R.id.listView in your R.layout.activity_main

Comment: Not here man, in the main post and formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see you have a null object, myListView. 
Trying checking for null before setting the adapter. 
**EDIT**
The next line:

```
ListView mylistView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

is probably null. You must see why it is null. That's it, as far as I can see from the error and the code.
**EDIT 2**
Take a look at this tutorial it might help you see what you did wrong.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: yeah i know its giving me nul object but i adpted the arrray already that is why confused

Comment: you seem to have listview1 in your xml not listview. check my edited answer.

Comment: that is compile time error if it does happen i ll figure it out easily ,,i post it by mistake i edited the code

Comment: i found the error tried to run on different api 19 device in which its working fine but on api 22 device its giving me a error maybe api 22 support recycler view

Comment: run the tutorial from my answer, then try to see at different api levels.